# Limit HTTP response size on Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm writing http crawler using Spring WebFlux and it's easy to parallel execution and to have HTTP timeouts:

```
val sitesToCrawl: Flux<String> = streamOfUrl()
val concurrencyLimit = 100
sitesToCrawl.flatMap(
    { WebClient.create().get().uri(it).exchange().timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)) },
    concurrencyLimit
)
```

But how can I limit page response size, like I don't want to download more than 500KB of data for each URL. Reading HTTP header Content-Length is not reliable. I guess I need to go one level down and use byte buffers and Netty events directly, but would be nice to wrap that using Flux/Mono to keep using those primitives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot, you should create your `WebClient` using the auto-configured `WebClient.Builder`; this will reflect Spring Boot's opinions and will, for example, configure Jackson decoding according to the configuration options you've chosen.

You should also build one and use it for many requests, instead of creating a new client instance for each request - this is not efficient.

Now as of Spring Framework 5.1 (Spring Boot 2.1), Spring WebFlux ships with a filterfunction that does just this: it will read N bytes and then cancel the response (stop reading and close the connection). Note that this behavior is interesting if the response is rather large, but doing so will also make the connection unfit for reuse and it won't be returned to the connection pool. If you're crawling a lot of pages on the same host, connection pooling vs. creating new connections is an interesting tradeoff.

Now this should look like this:

```
@Component
public class CrawlingService {

  private WebClient webClient;

  public CrawlingService(WebClient.Builder builder) {
      this.webClient = builder.filter(ExchangeFilterFunctions.limitResponseSize(maxSize))
                    .build();
  }

  public Mono<Void> crawlPage(URI page) {
      return // use webClient here
  }  

}
```

If you're not ready to use Spring Boot 2.1 (it's not released yet), you can always look at the filter function implementation and copy/paste that code into your project, it's very short.